# Show Certain Table Rows From User Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show certain rows of an HTML table based on the selection of a user from a drop down list. As of right now, I can only get it to show the entire table rather than just the players from the selected team.

Right now I have a "Show/Hide" button that I would like to read the selection from the drop down list, keep all players from the selected team and hide all other rows from the table. As of right now, I have it manually set to "Boston Celtics" so that anyone on that team is hidden from the list. How can I re-write this to:

1. Use the team selected from the drop down list automatically instead of having it typed in like I currently do?
2. Reverse the logic and KEEP the players from the team selected in the drop down list?

```js
function selectTeamOne() {
  var teamlist1 = document.getElementById("teamList1");
  document.getElementById("selectedTeamOne").value = teamlist1.options[teamlist1.selectedIndex].text;
}

function team1Click() {
  $('td:contains("Boston Celtics")').parent().toggle();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Select Team 1:
  <select id="teamList1" onchange="selectTeamOne()">
    <option>Atlanta Hawks</option>
    <option>Boston Celtics</option>
    <option>Brooklyn Nets</option>
    <option>Charlotte Hornets</option>
    <option>Chicago Bulls</option>
    <option>Cleveland Cavaliers</option>
    <option>Dallas Mavericks</option>
    <option>Denver Nuggets</option>
    <option>Detroit Pistons</option>
    <option>Golden State Warriors</option>
    <option>Houston Rockets</option>
    <option>Indiana Pacers</option>
    <option>Los Angeles Clippers</option>
    <option>Los Angeles Lakers</option>
    <option>Memphis Grizzlies</option>
    <option>Miami Heat</option>
    <option>Milwaukee Bucks</option>
    <option>Minnesota Timberwolves</option>
    <option>New Orleans Pelicans</option>
    <option>New York Knicks</option>
    <option>Oklahoma City Thunder</option>
    <option>Orland Magic</option>
    <option>Philadelphia 76ers</option>
    <option>Phoenix Suns</option>
    <option>Portland Trailblazers</option>
    <option>Sacramento Kings</option>
    <option>San Antonio Spurs</option>
    <option>Toronto Raptors</option>
    <option>Utah Jazz</option>
    <option>Washington Wizards</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type='button' value='Hide/Show' onclick="team1Click()" />

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>C.J. McCollum</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$3,302,849
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dennis Schroeder</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$2,616,965
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Isaac Fotu</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$473,604
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>JaVale McGee</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$11,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carmelo Anthony</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$20,571,468
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thomas Robinson</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$3,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jason Thompson</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$3,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Russell Westbrook</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$17,769,374
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>J.R. Smith</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$5,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeff Withey</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$885,120
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eric Moreland</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$792,682
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>David Wear</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$792,682
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bismack Biyombo</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$9,733,352
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carl Landry</td>
      <td>Boston Celtics</td>
      <td>$1,229,255
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mo Williams</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$5,215,311
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Trevor Booker</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$1,069,509
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lester Hudson</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$915,852
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blake Griffin</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$20,140,838
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Patrick Patterson</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$992,680
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jabari Brown</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$762,195
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Victor Oladipo</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$6,722,262
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kaleb Tarczewski</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$492,548
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>George Hill</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$8,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eric Maynor</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$2,090,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Robin Lopez</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$5,000,000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kris Humphries</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$1,352,181
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Earl Clark</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$1,069,509
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dominic McGuire</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$1,069,509
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tony Snell</td>
      <td>New York Knicks</td>
      <td>$885,120
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code to toggle visibility based on dropdown selected value

```
function team1Click() {
    var SelVal = $('#teamList1').find(':selected').text();
    var table = $('#mytable tbody tr');
    $.each(table, function (i) {
        if ($(table[i]).find('td:eq(1)').text().toLowerCase().trim() == SelVal.toLowerCase().trim()) {
            $(table[i]).hide();
        }
        else
            $(table[i]).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked but just needed to switch the .hide and .show to keep the correct data showing.

Comment: switch the .hide and .show accordingly, plz accept and vote

Comment: How can I set an initial value for the selected team so that the entire table (400+ players) Isn't displayed?

Comment: as i understand you want to set limited rows to be displayed for selected team

Comment: I want to show every player that is on the roster. This could range anywhere from 12-15 players per team. What I would like to do is have it so that when the page initially loads up not every single player on every team is listed, maybe just the ones on the first team listed (Atlanta Hawks).

Comment: try this one...............
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#teamList1').change(function () {
        team1Click();
    });

    $('#teamList1').change();
});

Answer (score 0):

In your first function selectTeamOne, you are looking for an element with id "selectedTeamOne" yet this element exists nowhere in the form you sent.

```
document.getElementById("selectedTeamOne").value = teamlist1.options[teamlist1.selectedIndex].text;
```

Since you tagged the question with jQuery, I will answer it using jQuery rather than pure javascript. It should answer both your A) and B) subpoints.

In the selectTeamOne() event handler, you can read the selected team's name using

```
var selectedTeamName = $('#teamList1 option:selected').text();
```

In order to get all the players that are not of this team, I'd again go with jQuery to select all tr where the second td does not match the selectedTeamName

```
$('#mytable tr').filter(function(index, element) {return !$('td:eq(1):contains("' + selectedTeamName + '")', element);}).hide()
```

The filter function uses the jquery selector context argument (i.e. element) to contextualize the search and restrict it to the tr it is currently evaluating, and its simply reversing the results of a search for the players ot the currently selected team.

In the end this filtered results set gets hidden with the call to hide.

Obviously you should also display the currently selected team, using the same code but without the negating clause and calling show() instead of hide ()

```
$('#mytable tr').filter(function(index, element) {return $('td:eq(1):contains("' + selectedTeamName + '")', element);}).show()
```